# Calculating % for one variable by 3 conditions suddenly gives an error message

Tags: r, percentage

Ok, I have a strange problem in my R code. I've got a dataset (in real its much larger):

```
Stomachdata_2017 = data.frame(Species= c('Herring','Herring','Cod','Cod','Cod','Cod','Shark', 'Shark', 'Shark'),
                FishID= c('1', '1', '2', '2', '3','3','4', '5','5'),
                StomachSp= c('Shrimp','Shrimp','Crab', 'Scad', 'Scad', 'Scad','Fish', 'Whiting', 'Fish'))
```

And I want to calculate the percentage of StomachSp per unique Species per unique FishID. I did this calculation before (see below):

```
#Sum for each unique species, FishID and unique stomach content the amount of prey items
    Stomach_perc <- count(unique(Stomachdata_2017), vars = c("Species", "FishID", "StomachSp"))
    Stomach_perc$Occ <- rep(1,nrow(Stomach_perc))
    Stomach_perc<-with(Stomach_perc,aggregate(Occ,by=list(Species=Species,StomachSp=StomachSp),function(x) sum(x)))
    Stomach_perc$Perc <- with(Stomach_perc, ave(x, Species, FUN=prop.table))
    Stomach_perc$Perc <- Stomach_perc$Perc * 100
```

But..when I ran the code again today it suddenly gave an error(?!) I never got before..and I did not change the code or anything. In this exampple it seem to work, but when I apply this code to my large dataset it suddenly stopt working...

```
Error: Column `vars` must be length 49 (the group size) or one, not 3
```

Can anyone help me? This is very frustrating...

Thank you

Comment: Your code showed the use of count but it wasn't clear whether its a function exported from plyr, or dplyr, or any other package. I have a suspicion that it's a name space problem. If you prefix your non base R functions with the package so `plyr::count()` instead of `count()` does it fix the issue?

Comment: You are my hero! Yes it worked! But how is it possible that it suddenly happened?

Comment: I posted a more elaborated explanation as an answer @Suusie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, the problem lies in namespace.

Consider you loaded the `plyr` library yesterday and then proceed to write the following code:

```
Stomach_perc <- count(unique(Stomachdata_2017), vars = c("Species", "FishID", "StomachSp"))
```

In this case, `count` is referring to the `count()` function exported by `plyr` package. At some point between yesterday and today, you may have also loaded a few other packages, the usual suspect include the likes of `tidyr` or `dplyr`. And some of these packages also export the function `count()`.

Today, when you execute the exact same code:

```
Stomach_perc <- count(unique(Stomachdata_2017), vars = c("Species", "FishID", "StomachSp"))
```

This time, `count()` could be a function exported from another package.

The specific problem of course is not with `count()`: It could happen to any function with sufficiently-common names. So use `dplyr::count()` to explicitly use the count function from that package.

As an aside, this is a pretty common scenario when writing code interactively, say in an R Markdown / R Notebook format. You may read in some library at line 43, go back and run code at line 20 and lo and behold, the code that once worked no longer work. Namespace!

Hadley Wickham's [material on this topic](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) is a great read!

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Wauw yes I see, indeed I added the library dply yesterday...Thank you very much for your help and explanation! :)